# Trying to post a list collection to the controller with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post a list collection to the controller with a full page post back to the server. The data from the client side is written with **JavaScript** / **jQuery** and the server code is written in **C#** using **ASP.Net MVC**.

I'm not sure what the issue is because when the ItemCheck method is hit with a breakpoint on the first curly brace after the method name but the model object Items property is null even though it's in the form data mentioned further below.

The code below is simplified for ease and is not working.

Input hidden field in the view where the JavaScript adds an item to it each time add button is pressed.

```
@model UI.ViewModels.ItemResource
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Items, new { @id = "Items" })
<button class="btn-default btn" id="AddItem" name="AddItem" type="button"  disabled>Add</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var items = [];
    // This code only adds an item to the items collection input hidden 
    // field for a full page post back to the server.
    var addItemToList = function () {

        var item = {
            ItemDate: $(date).val(),
            ItemAmount: $(amount).val()
        };
        items.push(item);
        $("#Items").val( JSON.stringify(items));
    };
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult ItemCheck(ItemViewModel model)
        {          
            if (result.IsValid)
            {
                model.Items = _anotherViewModel.Items;
                _anotherViewModel.Items= null;
                model.IsValid = _itemService.Save(model, _Itemhelper.GetUserId());
            } 
            else
            {
               //Validation here
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

ViewModels

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace UI.ViewModels.ItemResource
{
    public class ItemsViewModel
    {
        public ItemsViewModel()
        {
            Items = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        }

        [JsonBindable]
        public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }

        public decimal ItemAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FormData

```
Items: [{"ItemDate":"2020-06-05","ItemAmount":"2267"}]
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your controller ItemViewModel sb ItemsViewModel.

Comment: this is an array, so should be `List<ItemViewModel>` instead `ItemViewModel`

Comment: thanks @tstrand66 I've amended the above.

Comment: @Sajid where should the List of item view model go referring to your last message?

Comment: Parameter of the action like : `ItemCheck(List<ItemViewModel> model)`

Comment: I've added the items array in the JavaScript section please correct me if thing's aren't correct